# Passing a PHP variable into an Array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have the following simple array:

```
$q = array(1 => 
'My company, ABC is...',
'If only ABC was...'
);
```

What I would like to do is replace the word 'ABC' with a variable:

```
$q = array(1 => 
'My company, ".$name." is...',
'If only ".$name." was...'
);
```

However, the above simply adds the text in - I've tried double double quotes but no joy.  Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Please show your double quotes attempt

Comment: 'My company, "".$name."" is...',

Comment: It's been a long long day...apologies for the quality of this question!

Comment: is there a reason you are starting your `array` with position 1, instead of `array('My company, ABC is...', 'If only ABC was...');`

Comment: @BrettSantore - yes, I need it to start from 1 as opposed to 0, to match with question numbers - makes understanding the code easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use double quotes, use them like this:

```
$q = array(1 => 
  "My company, $name is...",
  "If only $name was..."
);
```

But even then, the variable will be substituted immediately, when the array is assigned. There is no binding that lets you insert a variable that is evaluated later.

Comment: Apolos, thanks for clarifying.  Can't believe I didn't spot the rather obvious flaw in my coding and thinking - it's been a long long day.

Comment: np. We've all had days like that. ;)

Comment: @Homer_J Don't forget to choose a correct answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $q = array(1 => 
      "My company, $name is...",
      "If only $name was..."
    );
```

`'My company, ".$name." is...'` will not work because the " is not stoping the string which in initialized with '.

The other way you could do it is with `"My company, ".$name." is..."` because the string is being terminated then appended to.